# Class implementing an interface must be declared before a children class?

Tags: php, inheritance, interface

I stumbled on an interesting issue today. In the context of a single file for multiple declarations, if class `B` implements interface `A`, and class `C` extends class `A`, class `B` must be declared *before* class `C`.

The following code does not work:

```
interface A {}
class C extends B {} // Class 'B' not found
class B implements A {}
```

This fixes it:

```
interface A {}
class B implements A {}
class C extends B {} // Class 'B' is found
```

But this works fine:

```
class A {}
class C extends B {} // Class 'B' is found
class B extends A {}
```

These are my results on PHP 5.3.8 (Win32) and PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.6 w/ suhosin.

So the question is, **is this documented behavior?** Why would it work with classes but not interfaces? Or should this be considered a bug?

Let me know about your experience, before I go digging in the PHP's source code and/or open a PHP bug ticket. :)

Thanks!

*Note: I know it's just a matter of class declaration order, but this puzzles me... If it's inappropriate, please don't hesitate to close.*

Comment: Your 3rd code example that apparently works for you under windows doesn't work for me under Debian, PHP 5.3.8-1~dotdeb.2. I get the fatal error.

Comment: @N.B.: Interesting. Works for me in 5.3.3 on Ubuntu as well. Something is not consistent here, whether it's the behavior or the documentation.

Comment: I tested the code directly from shell (with `php -a`). There were no frameworks or autoloaders included by chance.

Comment: 3rd example also works for me on a mac using mamp pro.  Worked fine on PHP Versions 5.2.17 and 5.3.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is documented behavior:

> [**Object Inheritance (Note)**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php):
>
> Unless autoloading is used, then classes must be defined before they are used. **If a class extends another, then the parent class must be declared before the child class structure. This rule applies to class that inherit other classes and interfaces.**

> [**PHP: extends - Manual (Note)**](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)
>
> Classes must be defined before they are used! If you want the class Named_Cart to extend the class Cart, you will have to define the class Cart first. If you want to create another class called Yellow_named_cart based on the class Named_Cart you have to define Named_Cart first. To make it short: the order in which the classes are defined is important.

---

### Undefined Behavior (with added sarcasm)

Even though your third example might word, it's not said to work according to the documentation (and I cannot find any changelog entry stating that it's a feature brought in).

The documentation of PHP sadly isn't 100%, but you can only trust what you know, and the above quotes are all I can find regarding this matter.

You might call it a bug, but in C++ we would describe it as `undefined behavior` ie. something that shouldn't be relied on.

---

If the "standard" (documentation) doesn't mention it, it's not safe to use.

If the "standard" (documentation) doesn't mention it, it may make the universe implode - or a raptor jump through your window. **Do not do anything that can kill us all!**

Comment: Not necessarily true, my third example actually challenges that statement. Will see what I get with different versions of PHP...

Comment: +1 Thanks, this answers my question, but there's definitely something wrong here.

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine: No autoloader in place.

Comment: @refp: We're pretty far from `undefined behavior` in C++ here. There have been known issues with the PHP documentation not being up-to-date, like you mentionned, since there's no ISO standard to define what behavior is defined and what isn't. The documentation (and the language) is written by the community, so it's prone to be inaccurate (seen that a lot in the past). I can make the universe implode by accessing an uninitialized variable in C, but I don't think PHP is powerful enough to kill us all. :)

Comment: @netcoder I wrote it with a lot of sarcasm in between the lines, though I'll definitely quote you on that C is powerful enough to implode the universe, and that PHP isn't. I don't even like PHP, just happen to know too much about it. I have a longer break comping up (I'm at the office), I might take some time digging through the PHP source trying to find what's going on.